# Converting factor axis (with non-natural levels) into real-like axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset as follows: I have a data frame like this, called `data_frame_test`.

```
    Value              time     group

   3.96655960      0     184
  -8.71308460      0     184
 -11.11638947      0     184
  -6.84213562      11    184
  -1.25926609      11    184
  -4.60649529      11    184
   0.27577858      11    184
  11.85394249      20    184
  -0.27114563      20    184
   1.73081284      20    184
   1.78209915      20    184
  11.34305840      20    184
  13.49688263      20    184
  -7.54752045      20    184
 -13.63673286      25    184
  -5.75711517      25    184
   0.35823669      25    184
  -2.45237694      25    184
   0.49313087      0     66
  -9.04148674      0     66
 -15.50337906      0     66
 -17.51445351      0     66
 -10.66807098      0     66
  -2.24337845      5     66
 -13.79929533      5     66
   1.33287125      5     66
   2.22143402      5     66
  11.46484833      10    66
  23.26805916      10    66
   9.07377968      10    66
   4.28664665      10    66
```

I want to plot a boxplot of a value for each time point and group.

```
ggplot(data_frame_test, aes(x=factor(time), y=Value, colour = factor(group)))  + 
geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0, fill = "white", position="identity", alpha=.5) +
scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(-1:26), breaks = seq(-1:26))
```

This results in the following picture, which is almost right:
[image]
However, I lose values at zero, which I see if I remove axis scaling. How can I intoduce zero into axis?

[image]

Comment: You `data` example doesn't match your code. Please fix that.

Comment: you want `seq(-1,26)` not `seq(-1:26)`

Comment: @Chris sorry, misread your comment

Comment: You could use `position="dodge"` like this: `ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(time), y=Value, colour = factor(group))) + geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0, fill = "white", position="dodge", alpha=.5)`

Comment: @Chris : almost, when I make it `ggplot(data_frame_test, aes(x=factor(time), y=Value, colour = factor(group)))  + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0, fill = "white", position="identity", alpha=.5) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(-1:26), breaks = seq(-1:26))` I get a shifted X axis. This obviously has to do with factor levels, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: if what you want is the first graph, with an axis that goes from `-1` to `26`, you want `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = seq(-1,26), breaks = seq(-1,26))`. Look at the result of typing just `seq(-1:26)` in your console. Alternatively, you could just use `-1:26`

Comment: @Chris can you post it as an answer, I'd vote it up?